# Upstart: Start server after mongodb

Tags: upstart, mongodb

i would like to start a server after mongodb has started. Is it correct to use `start on started mongodb`?

Example upstart script:

```
start on started mongodb
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/myserver.pid --exec myserver >> /var/log/myserver.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know practically nothing about mongo. Never the less, the answer to your question would be "Yes, if there is a 'mongodb' upstart service".

There are a couple ways to check for this:

```
sudo initctl list | grep mongo
```

If this command returns anything, check that the service it lists matches the name you're using ('mongodb').

Other wise, check the contents of `/etc/init` (note, not `/etc/init.d`) and see if there is a mongo related .conf file. This will be the name of the service to use, meaning change your start on stanza to `start on started [service name]`.

If there is no mongo related upstart service, then mongo is still using init.d scripts. If that's the case you'll need to find or make a mongo upstart script, install it and disable the init.d scripts (I used `bum` for that).

Googling for that turns up a couple of options:

[Ubuntu upstart script for MongoDB with automatic repair](https://gist.github.com/onedesign/765458)

This one looks more complete:

[MongoDB multiple instance upstart scripts](https://gist.github.com/alex-klepa/2171496)

Comment: Unfortunately, mongodb seems to be using a init.d script. Thanks for clarifying, though!

Comment: It would be interesting to see if that multiple instance script link works. If you set that up, you wouldn't have to disable the init.d scripts. They do it with sym-links.

Comment: there are two versions of MongoDB available on the official repos from MongoDB, one is init.d based for Debian, and the other is upstart based for Ubuntu: see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/